# Sort records based on string

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql5

Please consider the table below

```
Id           F1          F2          
---------------------------
1            Nima        a
2            Eli         a
3            Arian       a
4            Ava         b
5            Arsha       b
6            Rozhan      c
7            Zhina       c
```

I want to display records by sorting `COLUMN F2` to display one record from each string category (a,b,c) in order

```
Id           F1          F2          
---------------------------
1            Nima        a
5            Arsha       b
6            Rozhan      c
2            Eli         a
4            Ava         b
7            Zhina       c
3            Arian       a
```

**NOTE**: a,b,c could be anything... it should take one record from one entry and then 2nd from 2nd entry.

I have used join, or group by records but no success.

Comment: MySQL 8.x or MySQL 5.x?

Comment: MySQL 5.x @salmanA

Comment: which version of mysql do you use? version 5.5/5.6/5.7/5.8

Comment: MySQL version 5.7

Comment: Enumerate rows for each `F2` value separately then use this number in sorting.

Answer (score 3):

> MySQL version 5.7 – Syed Saqlain

```sql
SELECT id, f1, f2
FROM ( SELECT t1.id, t1.f1, t1.f2, COUNT(*) cnt
       FROM test t1
       JOIN test t2 ON t1.f2 = t2.f2 AND t1.id >= t2.id
       GROUP BY t1.id, t1.f1, t1.f2 ) t3
ORDER BY cnt, f2;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8138bd9ab5be36ba534a258d20b2e555

Comment: taking too long to respond, table has 400k rows

Comment: @SyedSaqlain Create according composite index by `(f2, id)`.

Comment: @SyedSaqlain upgrade to 8.0. Or switch to MariaDB.

Answer (score 1):

ROW_NUMBER() alternative for lower version of MYSQL. This query will work for version 5.5, 5.6 & 5.7.

```
-- MySQL (v5.7)
SELECT t.id, t.f1, t.f2
FROM (SELECT @row_no:=CASE WHEN @db_names=d.f2 THEN @row_no+1 ELSE 1 END AS row_number
           , @db_names:= d.f2
           , d.f2
           , d.f1
           , d.id
      FROM test d,
      (SELECT @row_no := 0,@db_names:='') x
      ORDER BY d.f2) t
ORDER BY t.row_number, t.f2
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=02dbb0086a6dd7c926d55a690bffbd06

Comment: taking too long to respond, table has 400k rows

Comment: Create an index and update version

Answer (score -1):

You can use window functions in the `order by`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by row_number() over (partition by f2 order by id),
         f2;
```

The `row_number()` function (as used above) assigns a sequential number starting with `1` to each value of `f2`.

In older versions of MySQL, you can use a correlated subquery instead:

```
order by (select count(*) from t t2 where t2.f2 = t.f2 and t2.id <= t.id),
         f2;
```

For performance, you want an index on `(f2, id)`.

Comment: I think that OP have downvoted it because he cannot apply it on his MySQL version (5.7). Of course I may be wrong...

Comment: taking too long to respond, table has 400k rows

Comment: @SyedSaqlain . . . Try with the specified index.